# Use AWS SDK on Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I'm trying to send an email using SES from an Azure Function with JavaScript (node.js), and the most straightforward way to do this is with the AWS SDK.

I've tried going into the Console and using:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm cache clean
npm install aws-sdk
```

While `npm install` works for other packages, it does not work for `aws-sdk`:

```
> npm install aws-sdk
Bad Request
```

It looks like this package is available: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

How can I get the aws-sdk package installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define aws-sdk package in `package.json` and then run `npm install`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management